# add Photo to Google map API Pin at Xamarin

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a photo in a Google map API pin in my Xamarin mobile app like the Yelp application does (as shown in the screenshot below).

```
LatLng loc = new LatLng(30.0444, 31.2357);
MarkerOptions pin = new MarkerOptions();
pin.SetPosition(loc);
pin.SetTitle( "CAIRO");
pin.SetSnippet("CAIRO");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a custom info window. With them you're able to customize the contents and design of the popup that opens when user clicks the marker.

Take a look at the official documentation concerning [info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows). The part *Custom info windows* is the most important for you.

1. You need to create a custom xml layout file that describes the info window layout. You can find an example [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3789/googlemap-setinfowindowadapter-now-working).
2. After that you have to implement your own implementation of the `IInfoWindowAdapter` interface. The Xamarin forum post I linked to above also has an example of this.

   ```
   public class CustomMarkerPopupAdapter : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter { }
   ```

I also found a video that describes the whole process of [creating a custom info window](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xglNnK6xXYY).

Comment: really appreciate for your help